# Why multi-column key (composite in Cassandra's concept) is not supported in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, database-performance

I recently transitioned from Cassandra to DynamoDB, and found a difference between the two (pretty significant to me at least). The terms are a bit different, so for simplicity I will just call them `partition key` and `clustering key`.

In Cassandra we have this concept called `composite key` - the partition key can be a multi-column value, as well as the clustering key. However, it looks like there's no such concept in DynamoDB. The [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html) mentions `composite`, but it just means a primary key can be formed by <partition_key, clustering_key>:

> Partition key and sort key – Referred to as a composite primary key, this type of key is composed of two attributes. The first attribute is the partition key, and the second attribute is the sort key.

I used the multi-column value (which is `composite` in Cassandra's sense) as keys a lot in the past so I was kind of shocked when I realized it's not supported in DynamoDB. I know it's always an option to do concatenation like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317994/composite-key-in-dynamodb-with-more-than-2-columns). My questions are:

1. Is having a multi-column value as the partition key an anti-pattern? Is this also true for clustering key?
2. Would a multi-column key cause performance degradation?
3. If there's no performance degradation, then what are other tradeoffs behind these two implementations?

Comment: The key for a DynamoDB table is explained here - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: @Aaron oh thanks for the reminder, didn't know this rule before... for people who is new to this like me, here's a related post :)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at how Cassandra implements composite partition keys, you'll see it simply serializes the multiple partition-key columns into a single key stored in the sstable (I wrote once a detailed explanation on this, in https://docs.scylladb.com/architecture/sstable/sstable2/sstable-data-file/ - for the open-source Scylla project which reimplements both Cassandra and DynamoDB).

DynamoDB chose not to do this serialization for you, and ask you to do it yourself (this what you call concatenation). I don't think there was any particular reason why they chose to do this - I think it just simplifies the API.

The only downside I can think of with not having composite keys is that you are not able to **index** parts of the composite key. In Cassandra, if (a,b) is a composite partition key, you can add a materialized view whose partition key is just just a (with b part of the clustering key). In DynamoDB you can't do that with a GSI (DynamoDB's parallel of Cassandra's materialized views).